# url rewriting : can't find rule for /fr/ or /en/

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to identified urls that are either "/fr/" or "/en/". (and only these two)
I'm looking for the good regular expression.

Of course it works if I write "/../", but it's too large.

Best I could find is "/[fe][rn]/" but it also take /fn/ and /er/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a pipe in a group :

```
/(fr|en)/?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Edit:** added the optional trailing slash

Comment: Ok It works. Didn't know the pipe. It's not listed in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/rewrite/intro.html.

Comment: Is it also possible to have also "/fr" and "/en" (without the last '/') and "/" in the same regex? would be helpful.

Comment: Of course, add an optional multiplicator on the last slash : `/(fr|en)/?`

Comment: Ok perfect, what i need is /(fr|en)?/?. That whay all these are redirected : /,/en,/en/,/fr,/fr/. thx

Comment: You should better use `/((fr|en)/?)?` then, to avoid `//` to match.